# Помогите с фоном блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать так чтобы было как на изображении - 1 [image]

У меня почему-то фон блока с текстом помещает в себя и кружок(before).

[image]

```css
.r_title {
  background: #ebebeb;
  width: 470px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.r_title::before {
  content: '';
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #445161;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}


/*НЕ ОБРАЩАТЬ ВНИМАНИЯ!*/

.r_title h4 {
  color: #333;
  font-style: italic;
}

.r_title p {
  color: #989898;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_title">
  <h4>
    Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus commodi consectetur?
  </h4>
  <p>
    Lourens S.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так ?

```css
.odin{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.fl{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

.span1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.block2{
  width: 200px;
  /*height: 200px;*/
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.block2:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
 
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 40px;
  border: 20px solid transparent; border-right: 20px solid green;
}
.span2{
  color: tomato;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="odin">
  <div class="fl">
    <span class='span1'></span>
    <div class="block2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod ratione, a, mollitia, cumque voluptatibus pariatur non illo labore officia commodi cum necessitatibus ex. Ducimus reiciendis nam dolore a reprehenderit veritatis, fugit incidunt! At in iste quisquam dolor quas voluptate labore?
      <span class="span2">Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Допустим так

```css
body {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.r_title {
  width: 776px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

.r_title .circle {
 min-width: 124px;
 height: 124px;
 background: #445161;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.r_title .description {
 padding: 22px;
 background-color: #ebebeb;
 border-radius: 15px;
 position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.r_title .description:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 right: 100%;
 top: 62px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent #ebebeb transparent transparent;
}

.r_title h4 {
  color: #565656;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.r_title p {
  color: #989898;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_title">
 <div class="circle"></div>
 <div class="description">
  <h4>Porro officia cumque sint deleniti nemo facere rem vitae odit inventore cum odio, iste quia doloribus autem aperiam nulla ea neque reprehenderit. Libero doloribus, possimus officiis sapiente necessitatibus commodi consectetur?</h4>
  <p>Lourens S.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для .r_title вместо padding задать margin. 
Для .r_title::before указать left: -90px;(ну или подогнать свое значение)

```css
.r_title {
    background: #ebebeb;
    width: 470px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.r_title::before {
    content: '';
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #445161;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
    top: 0;
}
```